# Angular Kendo grid view & list View & Details View

Tags: html, angular, listview, gridview, kendo-ui

I have a requirement in kendo grid, like 
 when I click some icons I need to change the format of data source`(grid view | list view\ details view).`

Like this [sample](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_list_grid_view.asp) I need to do in Kendo grid. I am searched lot in google but I am unable to get any sample for this requirement. Is anyone done this in your project by using kendo grid?

Comment: In theory you can dynamically change the template name and re-render the grid. Here is how to use the template https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/

Comment: @CarlosMartins Here we needed some manual customization. So it's not possible  without those manual works . right?

Comment: true, you need the logic to swap the template and also design 2 different templates for the same data. There is also some logic you can implement inside one kendo template. depending on the complexity of the template this can be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459463/kendo-ui-grid-if-else-condition