# How to write IF condition in kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement, kendo-grid

I would like to use a if condition in kendo grid column. But it doesn't work. I would like to put images depends on condition. Is there syntax error?

```
<kendo-grid-column field ="Scanned_STS" title="Status" width="20">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem> "# if(Scanned_STS == 1) { #  #= "<img src=''>" # # } else if (Scanned_STS == 0) { # #= "<img src=''>" # # }"</ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Here are some good examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459463/kendo-ui-grid-if-else-condition.  'Hope that helps...

Comment: I already tried that before...but it's not working

Comment: 1) You'll noticed the examples use JS; you're doing it directly in the HTML.  You might try working closer to the examples.  2) Instead of `<img src=...>` HTML, you should probably 2a) specify a class for the icon, then 2b) map the class to an image in separate .css.  'Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Hi If your working with angular you could use [NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { sampleProducts } from './products';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
         <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                    <strong>{{dataItem.ProductName}}</strong>
                      <img *ngIf='dataItem.Discontinued' src='' alt='Item Discontinued'/>
                      <img *ngIf='!dataItem.Discontinued' src='' alt='Item Continued'/>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public gridData: any[] = sampleProducts;
}
```