# Kendo Jquery Grid - Need to hide Delete button Based on row wise hidden value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have a kendo jquery grid, we need to hide the Delete button row wise based on hidden column value. It is working fine, but after click on Edit and click on Cancel, Delete button appears again. In Grid Databound i am doing this :

```
 dataBound: function (e) {
                //Selects all delete buttons
                $("#grid tbody tr .k-grid-Delete").each(function () {
                    var currentDataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
                    //Check in the current dataItem if the row is deletable
                    if (currentDataItem && currentDataItem.source == '2') {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                })
            },
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I prefer column templates for this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459463/kendo-ui-grid-if-else-condition)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `dataBound` event, use `visible` property in the `command` column. So that it will not display the delete button even you update/cancel the value.

Example:

```
{ command: [{name: "edit"},{ name: "destroy", visible: function(dataItem) { return dataItem.ProductName!="Chai" } }] }],
```

**Below is the excutable example:**

[Using visible for destroy command](https://dojo.telerik.com/OyufAxaP)

**API Reference:**
[API Reference](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.command#columnscommandvisible)

Comment: Thanks, although I cannot use it due to the lower kendo version of what we are using. Thanks again

Comment: which kendo version you are using?